# Google Maps Activty Unable to start

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to show maps in my `Activity` using Google Play services 
but when I start the `Activity` it gives me `RunTimeException`

Here is the Java code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyMap extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_map);

    try {
        // Loading map
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }

 private void initilizeMap() {
     if (googleMap == null) {
         googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                 R.id.map)).getMap();

         // check if map is created successfully or not
         if (googleMap == null) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                     .show();
         }
     }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     initilizeMap();
 }

}
```

and here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is what the LogCat says when I start the `Activity`:

```
06-01 03:33:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 03:33:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2744): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.tracker/com.project.tracker.MyMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
06-01 03:33:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
06-01 03:33:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
06-01 03:33:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
06-01 03:33:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2744):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
06-01 03:33:59.207: E/AndroidRuntime(2744):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Comment: instead of using the map fragment use the supportmapfragment in your xml

Answer (score 2):

You should change this

```
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

to

```
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and also change

```
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

to

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```